# node js mysql connection error "Incomplete response received from application"

Tags: mysql, node.js

while trying to upload my nodejs app, using shared hosting (Cpanel), I kept on getting this response even though my code works fine on localhost.

using mysql2 as my method of connecting
node version 14.20.0, on both my local and the Cpanel.

it worked at first but something went wrong.

connecting my server to the database

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest versions and The best way to stay away from these incidents is to use Docker.